# Is it possible to write a custom loss function that is based on the difference of sample outputs in a batch in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a loss function in Keras, which can do the following:

Suppose y0, y1, ..., yn is the model **batch output** for a batch input x0, x1, ..., xn, here batch_size is n+1, the output yi for each xi is a scalar value, what I want the loss function to calculate the **whole loss** for this batch as following:

K.log(K.sigmoid(y1-y0))+K.log(K.sigmoid(y2-y1))+...+K.log(K.sigmoid(yn-yn-1))

I was thinking to use Lambda layer to first convert the batch output[y0,y1,...,yn] to [y1-y0,  y2-y1, ...,yn-yn-1], then use a custom loss function on the transformed output.

However, I am not sure if Keras can understand that there is no weight to update in the Lambda layer, and I am not clear **how Keras will propagate the gradient back through the Lambda layer**, as Keras usually requires each layer/loss function operates on single sample input, but my layer will take the whole output of a batch of samples. Have anyone solved similar issues before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the slicing like below work for you (though I am not using keras).

```py
batch = 4
num_classes = 6
logits = tf.random.uniform(shape=[batch, num_classes])

logits1 = tf.slice(logits, (0, 0), [batch, num_classes-1])
logits2 = tf.slice(logits, (0, 1), [batch, num_classes-1])

delta = logits2 - logits1
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(tf.nn.sigmoid(delta)), axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  logits, logits1, logits2, delta, loss  = sess.run([logits, logits1, logits2, 
                                                     delta, loss])

  print 'logits\n', logits
  print 'logits2\n', logits2
  print 'logits1\n', logits1
  print 'delta\n', delta
  print 'loss\n', loss
```

The result:

```sh
logits
[[ 0.61241663  0.70075285  0.98333454  0.4117974   0.5943476   0.84245574]
 [ 0.02499413  0.22279179  0.70742595  0.34853518  0.7837007   0.88074362]
 [ 0.35030317  0.36670768  0.64244425  0.87957716  0.22823489  0.45076978]
 [ 0.38116801  0.39040041  0.82510674  0.64789391  0.45415008  0.03520513]]
logits2
[[ 0.70075285  0.98333454  0.4117974   0.5943476   0.84245574]
 [ 0.22279179  0.70742595  0.34853518  0.7837007   0.88074362]
 [ 0.36670768  0.64244425  0.87957716  0.22823489  0.45076978]
 [ 0.39040041  0.82510674  0.64789391  0.45415008  0.03520513]]
logits1
[[ 0.61241663  0.70075285  0.98333454  0.4117974   0.5943476 ]
 [ 0.02499413  0.22279179  0.70742595  0.34853518  0.7837007 ]
 [ 0.35030317  0.36670768  0.64244425  0.87957716  0.22823489]
 [ 0.38116801  0.39040041  0.82510674  0.64789391  0.45415008]]
delta
[[ 0.08833623  0.28258169 -0.57153714  0.18255019  0.24810815]
 [ 0.19779766  0.48463416 -0.35889077  0.43516552  0.09704292]
 [ 0.01640451  0.27573657  0.23713291 -0.65134227  0.22253489]
 [ 0.0092324   0.43470633 -0.17721283 -0.19374382 -0.41894495]]
loss
[-3.41376281 -3.11249781 -3.49031925 -3.69255161]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to reduce the batch_size dimension by 1, not the feature dimension, this is confusing, I will update the question with more clarification.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, if the reduction is on batch, why would the similar slicing not work?

Comment: This is what I meant: ```logits = tf.random.uniform(shape=[batch, 1])
logits1 = tf.slice(logits, (0, 0), [batch-1, 1])
logits2 = tf.slice(logits, (1, 0), [batch-1, 1])```

Comment: Thanks Greeness! This is similar to what I did earlier, I used y_pred[1:,:]-y_pred[:-1,:] directly, the code can run, but it seems keras didn't get the backpropagation right, it needs the custom loss function to return the loss for each sample, when I lump them together, it couldn't figure out how to break them down. Do you have any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: I see your point. I did some search and found this pending issue, which seems quite related: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22059. If I understand it correctly, we are also optimizing a slice of variable.

Comment: Thanks Greeness! I know we can implement this in caffe, but not sure about tensorflow, I am also researching, please let me know if you find anything else.